# Installing Object_Recognition_Core on ubuntu python link errors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install object_recognition_core by following the instructions on this website wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install

Upon running catkin_make it gets to 100% then fails with the following link errors:

```
    /home/aly/workspace/ork/devel/lib/libobject_recognition_core_common.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyObject_Size'
/home/aly/workspace/ork/devel/lib/libobject_recognition_core_common.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyErr_Occurred'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyList_Insert'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyExc_ImportError'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyString_InternFromString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyProperty_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libboost_python.so: error: undefined reference to 'PyString_AsString'
```

and many more similar errors followed by:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ork/devel/lib/object_recognition_ros/object_information_server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [object_recognition_ros/src/info_service/CMakeFiles/object_information_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Any idea why these are failing, my python version is 2.7.3

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105706/installing-object_recognition_core-on-ubuntu-python-link-errors/) by [o3p7s5](https://answers.ros.org/users/9096/o3p7s5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What system are you using? What Distro?

I just got ORK up and running on Hydro and Groovy. I had similar problems installing on Ubuntu. I think this is how I got it installed correctly (from the top of the Install page):

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-object-recognition-core    %installs core
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-object-recognition*        %installs all other packages

**of course replace "Hydro" with your particular distro. This should install it directly from the ROS repositories.

it should install everything to /opt/ros/hydro/share.

Make sure to source your .bashrc file to opt/ros/hydro/devel/setup.sh if you have not done so already. Otherwise ORK will not be on your ROS_Path.

Also, a new google group was just started for ORK: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/object-recognition-kitchen

---

Originally posted by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) with karma: 88 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [o3p7s5](https://answers.ros.org/users/9096/o3p7s5/) on 2013-12-01**:
Dear Chase,
thank you for your reply. I also run ubuntu 12.04 on a 64 bit System. I already tried groovy and hydro. The thing is that I want to modify the source codes of ORK in order of getting better results in linemod. I had it building the code about a month ago till last week. Since one week it is not possible to buile (catkin_make) ORK. Doesn't matter if groovy or hydro.
I even made a clean install and followed exactly the instructures on

```
http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install
```

I realy need to get over this problems, and I dont have a clue why these happen..
May be I should check out an older base line from git...

Best Regards,
o3p7s5